# Slight difference in definitions of Glassers Master Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I’m probably misreading but there seems to be a slight difference in the definition of Glasser’s Master Theorem between [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem) and [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html).

The difference lies in the substitution $u$ and $\phi(x)$ with $u$ having $x - a - \sum$ over $x - \sum$.

Are these equivalent? Is there an error with one?

Comment: The definition on math world is broken. It should not have a $|a|$ in front of $x$. The missing of $- a$ is  relatively minor. When in doubt, read the original:

Glasser, M. L. "A Remarkable Property of Definite Integrals." Math. Comput. 40, 561-563, 1983.

An online copy of that paper can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1983-40-162/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1.pdf).

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer, I think it a sufficient answer :)

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Agreed. Please post